# multi level filtering by index of customized list in java 11

Tags: java, sorting, collections, atomicinteger

Instead of adding and updating these extra sequential number fields, I found useful two stage solution when processing well sorted multi-level collections for GUI (where row indexes are calculated on fly):

```
ParentEntity filterByParentAndChildListsIndexes(List<ParentEntity> parents, Integer prntIdx, Integer chldIdx){
   AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger(1); // may be '0'
   Optional<ParentEntity> parentOp = parents.stream().filter(p -> idx.getAndIncrement() == prntIdx).findFirst();
   if (parentOp.isPresent()){
      return childFilter(parentOp.get(), chldIdx);
   }
   return null;
}

ChildEntity childFilter(ParentEntity parent, Integer chldIdx){
   AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger(1); // may be '0'
   return parent.getChildEntities().stream().filter(c -> idx.getAndIncrement() == chldIdx).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

but it seems redundant and not flexible... so, I would be grateful for suggestions on existing solutions or suggestions for recursion of such multilevel filters.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
parents.stream()
        .skip(prntIdx)
        .limit(1)
        .map(ParentEntity::getChildEntities)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .skip(chldIdx)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null)
```

Or just use `List.get()`:

```
if (prntIdx < parents.size()) {
    List<ChildEntity> children = parents.get(prntIdx).getChildEntities();
    if (chldIdx < children.size()) {
        return children.get(chldIdx);
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: `flatMap` will flatten all subsequent elements. So if `chldIdx` is equal or greater than the child list, it will continue with the next parent’s children. You have to use `.skip(prntIdx).limit(1)` to avoid this. But it’s far better to use `List.get()` here anyway…

Comment: Thanks, my bad, have updated the answer. I also agree it's much better to use `List.get()`

Comment: So, simple, so good. Thanks for best solution.